# I want to filter array of objects with a string that should match with a objects property key and should check that key value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
const workSchedule = [
    {
        name: 'a',
        age: 21,
        workDays: {
            monday: {isavailable:true}, tuesday:{isavailable:false}, wednesday:{isavailable:true}, thursday:{isavailable:true}, Friday:{isavailable:false}
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        age: 22,
        workDays: {
            monday: {isavailable:false}, tuesday:{isavailable:false}, wednesday:{isavailable:true}, thursday:{isavailable:false}, Friday:{isavailable:false}
        }
    }
]
```

and I have a string variable which have a selected Day

```
 const day='Monday'
```

Now I want to check if the person A or B is available on monday or not?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to solve this problem to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: Please be consistent with casing in variable names? `workSchedule` and `isavailable` is rather annoying.

Comment: Also: what kind of output are you expecting? That will have a huge bearing on how the code queries/manipulates the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```js
  const workSchedule = [
    {
      name: "a",
      age: 21,
      workDays: {
        monday: { isavailable: true },
        tuesday: { isavailable: false },
        wednesday: { isavailable: true },
        thursday: { isavailable: true },
        friday: { isavailable: false },
      },
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      age: 22,
      workDays: {
        monday: { isavailable: false },
        tuesday: { isavailable: false },
        wednesday: { isavailable: true },
        thursday: { isavailable: false },
        friday: { isavailable: false },
      },
    },
  ];

  const day = "Monday";

  workSchedule.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.workDays[day.toLocaleLowerCase()]["isavailable"]) {
      console.log(e.name + " is available");
    } else {
      console.log(e.name + " is not available");
    }
  });
```

Comment: This will not work if day variable is set to "Friday".

Comment: Yes agreed, but keys should be in lower case.

Comment: You can use ```day = day.toLowerCase();``` when you do the check but this is inconsistent to use upper and lower case letters in the initial object I agree.
It's better too to check if the variable name exist in the Object before to compare the values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to achieve what you want, but you should try to write the code you have tried so far to reach your goal.

Also, think to be consistent in the variables names in your Object "Friday" the first letter is an upper case.

The first snippet is just to do what you asked, the second one is more reusable to have access to the availablePersons Array out of the function.

```js
        const workSchedule = [
          {
            name: 'a',
            age: 21,
            workDays: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: false },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: false }
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'b',
            age: 22,
            workDays: {
              monday: { isavailable: false },
              tuesday: { isavailable: false },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: false },
              friday: { isavailable: false }
            }
          }
        ];
        
        function getAvailablePersons(day){
            let lowercaseDay = day.toLowerCase();

            // Array to store available persons
            let availablePersons = [];

            workSchedule.forEach(person => {
              if (
                person.workDays &&
                person.workDays.hasOwnProperty(lowercaseDay) &&
                person.workDays[lowercaseDay].isavailable
              ) {
                availablePersons.push(person);
              }
            });

            // Display available persons
            console.log(`available persons on ${day}: (${availablePersons.length})`);
            availablePersons.forEach(person => {
              console.log(`- ${person.name}`);
            });
        }
        
        getAvailablePersons('Monday');
        getAvailablePersons('Wednesday');
```

Here's a better and more reusable snippet Where you retrieve an **Array of Objects that contains the available persons only**, so you can realize other searches on those persons :

```js
        const workSchedule = [
          {
            name: 'a',
            age: 21,
            workDays: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: false },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: false }
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'b',
            age: 22,
            workDays: {
              monday: { isavailable: false },
              tuesday: { isavailable: false },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: false },
              friday: { isavailable: false }
            }
          }
        ];
        
        let availablePersons = [];
        let day = null;
        
        function getAvailablePersons(aDay){
            let lowercaseDay = aDay.toLowerCase();

            // Array to store available persons
            availablePersons = [];

            workSchedule.forEach(person => {
              if (
                person.workDays &&
                person.workDays.hasOwnProperty(lowercaseDay) &&
                person.workDays[lowercaseDay].isavailable
              ) {
                availablePersons.push(person);
              }
            });
            return availablePersons;
        }
        
        function listPersons(day){
            // Display available persons
            day = day.toLowerCase();
            console.log(`available persons on ${day}: (${availablePersons.length})`);
            availablePersons.forEach(person => {
              console.log(`- ${person.name}`);
            });
        }
        
        day = 'Monday';
        let personsOnMonday = getAvailablePersons(day);
        console.log(personsOnMonday);
        listPersons(day);
        
        day = 'Wednesday';
        let personsWednesday = getAvailablePersons(day);
        console.log(personsWednesday);
        listPersons(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply with filter method.

```js
        const day = 'monday';
        const workSchedule = [
        {
            name: 'a',
            age: 21,
            workDays: {
                monday: {isavailable:true}, tuesday:{isavailable:false}, wednesday:{isavailable:true}, thursday:{isavailable:true}, Friday:{isavailable:false}
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'b',
            age: 22,
            workDays: {
                monday: {isavailable:false}, tuesday:{isavailable:false}, wednesday:{isavailable:true}, thursday:{isavailable:false}, Friday:{isavailable:false}
            }
        }
    ];

    
const available = workSchedule.filter(sch=> sch.workDays[day.toLowerCase()].isavailable === true);


console.log(available[0]);
console.log(available[0].name);
```

Comment: In condition, try to pass the variable instead of hard coded monday as that can be any day value.

Comment: Yes. Will not work for day other than monday

Comment: @Hetal N Try the code again I've updated it.

Comment: The day is dynamic, If a user selects tuesday , he wants to see which persons are available on tuesday and I want  the result  to store in a variable

Comment: @fallen1202 I've added day as the variable now. You should run the code again. Thanks.

Comment: @fallen1202 : The only issue with this approach is that the Array : available don't contains all the properties of the persons that match the criteria and you have to loop all the items in the array just to know the persons who are available.

So, in case of a bigger Array of Objects, I think that's better to retrieve another Array of objects with all the persons who matches the criteria even if this code is shorter than mine.

it's a matter of trade-offs between code length, efficiency, and code organization. Choose the approach that aligns best with your needs. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

First you should standardise your input data to make it consistent (`friday` instead of `Friday`, for example, and `isAvailable` instead of `isavailable`).

The answer depends on what kind of data you're expecting as output. This will inform how the data is meant to be queried and manipulated.

Here are a few examples.

---

1. Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of names we can assign to a variable called `isAvailableOnMonday`.

```js
const workSchedule=[{name:"a",age:21,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!0},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!0},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}},{name:"b",age:22,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!1},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!1},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}}];
const day = 'Monday';

// Accepts the data and day as arguments
function finder(data, day) {

  // For each object in the data...
  return data.filter(obj => {

    // Destructure `name` and `workDays` from the object
    const { name, workDays } = obj;

    // Check to see if that day is available (making sure you
    // render the day string to lower case)
    return workDays[day.toLowerCase()].isAvailable;

  // Finally `map` over the returned array of objects and
  // extract their names into a new array
  }).map(obj => obj.name);

}

const isAvailableOnMonday = finder(workSchedule, day);
console.log(isAvailableOnMonday);
```

---

2. In this example we're just using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the data objects to return a new array of objects that describes if a particular day `isAvailable`.

```js
const workSchedule=[{name:"a",age:21,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!0},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!0},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}},{name:"b",age:22,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!1},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!1},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}}];
const day = 'Monday';

// Accepts the data and day as arguments
function finder(data, day) {

  // For each object in the data...
  return data.map(obj => {

    // Destructure `name` and `workDays` from the object
    const { name, workDays } = obj;

    // Check to see if that day is available (making sure you
    // render the day string to lower case)
    const isAvailable = workDays[day.toLowerCase()].isAvailable;

    // Return a new object that specifies the name, day, and
    // availability as key/value pairs
    return { name, day, isAvailable };
  });
}

console.log(finder(workSchedule, day));
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

---

3. In this example, we're using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object that places the names of people in an `isAvailable` array for a particular day.

```js
const workSchedule=[{name:"a",age:21,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!0},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!0},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}},{name:"b",age:22,workDays:{monday:{isAvailable:!1},tuesday:{isAvailable:!1},wednesday:{isAvailable:!0},thursday:{isAvailable:!1},friday:{isAvailable:!1}}}];
const day = 'Monday';

// Accepts the data and day as arguments
function finder(data, day) {

  // For each object in the data...
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

    // Destructure `name` and `workDays` from the object
    const { name, workDays } = obj;

    // Create an object key using the lowercase'd day value
    const key = day.toLowerCase();

    // Check to see if that day is available
    const { isAvailable } = workDays[key];

    // If the day doesn't exist as a key on the output object
    // add it and initialise it to an object with an empty
    // `isAvailable` array
    acc[key] ??= { isAvailable: [] };
    
    // The day _is_ available add the name to the `isAvailable`
    // array for that day
    if (isAvailable) acc[key].isAvailable.push(name);
    
    // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
    return acc;
  
  }, {});

}

console.log(finder(workSchedule, day));
```